# ChipScope Error - Did not find trigger mark in buffer

Tags: fpga, xilinx, virtex, xilinx-ise

**Has anybody mentioned data errors, trigger error or upload errors in ChipScope?**

I'm using ChipScope (from ISE 14.7) with the IP core flow. So I created 15 different ICON IP cores as ngc files and wrapped them all in a VHDL module. This module chooses by generic with ngc file should be instantiated. So I can easily choose the number of active VIO/ILA cores.

Currently my project has 2 VIO cores and 5 ILA cores, utilizing circa 190 BlockRAMs on a Kintex-7 325T (>400 BlockRAMs in total). When a trigger event occurs, I get sometimes the warning *Did not find trigger mark in buffer. Data buffer may be corrupted.* or *Data upload error*.

This error is independent of the trigger mode (normal trigger event, immediate trigger, startup trigger). It seams to happen mostly on Unit 4 (91 bit data * 32k depth + 3 trigger ports each of 4 units). The upload progress bar can stops at any percentage from 1 to 95% as far as I noticed.

Additionally I get hundreds of these warnings:

```
Xst - Edge .../TransLayer_ILA2_ControlBus<14> has no source ports and will not be translated to ABC.
```

My google research: ignore them :)

There is also a bug in XST: This warning has no ID and can't be filtered :(

**As of now, I tried to fix this problem:**

- Reduced / Increased JTAG speed -> no effect (program device is not effected)
- recompiled ip core / new ngc file
- reduced ILA windows size

So what can it be?

P.S. All timings are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and a solution.

The problem: I changed one ILA coregenerator file's name and it's contents (modified internal name with an editor). But I missed one parameter so CoreGen generated some sources under the old name. This was still in usage by another ILA core, so one of them got overwritten.

Solution:
I opened every ILA xco file and every cgp file and check all names.